# Insert Value at a particular row and column index in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing validation on columns of a dataframe and need to generate another dataframe which will store generated error

example dataframe:

```
                Date Clearing Member PAN Trading Member PAN   CPCode       CPPAN
0     01-12-2021          AAACM6094BBB       AAACM6094R      124  GMAPS5536A
1     01-12-2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A
2     01-10-2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A
3     01-15-2021          AAACM6094RBBB      AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A
4     01-16-2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R      123  GMAPS5536A
```

Performing Validation on "Date" Column

```
PANValidation = r"^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}"
DateFormatValidation=r"^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-]\d{4}"
    rslt_df1=vaex_df2[~vaex_df2['Date'].apply(str).str.contains(DateFormatValidation, regex=True)].index   
    for i in rslt_df1:
        print(i)
```

Gives me values :

```
3,4
```

Need to add this in a dataframe of having Column as Errors
example df=

```
   Errors
3  "Date Format incorrect"
4  "Date Format incorrect"
```

After doing Validation over "Clearing Member PAN"

```
rslt_df1=vaex_df2[~vaex_df2['Clearing Member PAN'].apply(str).str.contains(PANValidation, regex=True)].index   
for i in rslt_df1:
    print(i)
    Errordf.at[i+1,1] = 'Invalid Pan'
```

Resulted Error dataframe should be :

```
   Errors
0  "Invalid Pan"
3  "Date Format incorrect","Invalid Pan"
4  "Date Format incorrect"
```

And similarly validation over all columns

I tried few things but it doesn't giving me how it needs to be

```
Errordf = pd.DataFrame(columns='Error File'])
rslt_df1=vaex_df2[~vaex_df2['Date'].apply(str).str.contains(DateFormatValidation, regex=True)].index   
for i in rslt_df1:
    print(i)
    Errordf.at[i+1,1] = 'Date Format Incorrect'
```

How this can be approched ?
The idea behind creating errordataframe is so that I can export to Error csv at once

Comment: What are the validation functions you're applying on each column? For example, `DateFormatValidation`?

Comment: @not_speshal edited my question its just a regex.

Answer (score 0):

###### Algorithm:

- store the validation (regex expressions) for each column in a dictionary
- create a dataframe flagging error values for each column
- join all the errors to create the required series

###### Code:

```
validations = {"Date": r"^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-]\d{4}", 
               "Clearing Member PAN": r"^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}",
               "Trading Member PAN": r"^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}",
               "CPCode": r"[0-9]{3}",
               "CPPAN": r"^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}"}

errordf = pd.DataFrame()
for column in validations:
    errordf[column] = vaex_df2[column].astype(str).str.contains(validations[column], regex=True).replace({True: "", False: f"Invalid {column}"})
    
errordf = errordf.apply(";".join, axis=1).str.strip(";").rename("Error File")
```

###### Output:

```
>>> errrordf
0                
1                
2                
3    Invalid Date
4    Invalid Date
Name: Error file, dtype: object
~~~
```